# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 can't debug?

Tags: c++, compilation

I installed the program, and wrote a simple C program to try it, but I couldn't build it or anything !
The debug, build and run options are all greyed out ! I can't click them
Please help :(

Comment: Did you create a new project/solution?

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio your code needs to be in a Project before you can Build/Debug it. You can't just open your `.cpp` file and run it. (When you create a project, Visual Studio creates a solution to contain it (a solution can contain many projects))

You can Create a new project using `File -> New -> Project` :

[image]

then add your code to that project or if the you already have your source code files you can use the "Create a Project from Existing Code Files" wizard which is available under `File -> New -> Project from existing code`

[image]

Comment: I tried to create a project, but it says "Project creation failed" ?

Comment: That's all you got ? no details in the error message ? have you tried repairing your Visual Studio ?